# How to create a data-type that is a subset of possible values for another data-type

Tags: c#

How can I create a data type that only allows particular values of another data type. For example, let's say I want to create a type that's limited to the fifty states as strings. How would I go about doing that? Using an `enum` and then a helper function feels a bit hacky to me.

EDIT: I suppose it is late to add this, but a compile-time error checking solution would be ideal.

Comment: Still, that's the way to go.

Comment: @TylerCormpton Couldn't be better to organize these fifty states in more than an enumeration? I mean, by topic, by concept... I guess there's a better design than that.

Comment: This is exactly what an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx) is for - a finite set of distinct values.

Comment: `enum` actually allows every number, whenever defined or not. It's not limited at all.

Comment: Exactly... `enum`s are not well implemented in .NET so for particular cases there are really better solutions. Maybe you can describe your requirements a little more detailed... Do you have e.g. some additional data like names, descriptions, details, other members with your data items?

Comment: @CSharper, no additional data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class, and only allow specific values in the constructor. That way it's impossible to create an instance of the class that has an incorrect value. (Using an enum doesn't restrict the values to only the ones specified.)

Simple example:

```
public class Paint {

  public string Name { get; private set; }

  public Paint(string name) {
    switch (name) {
      case "Red":
      case "Green":
      case "Blue":
        Name = name;
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Illegal paint name '" + name + "'.");
    }
  }

}
```

Internally you can represent the value as a string or as an enum, that depends on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, an enum is really the best solution. For something more complex, you could use a factory method. Here's an example:

```
public class State
{
   public string Name { get; private set; }

   private State(string name)
   {
      this.Name = name;
   }

   public static State CreateState(string name)
   {
      // validate and throw error if invalid
      return new State(name);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 You could also provide singletons for all the possible values, such as `public static State Indiana = new State("Indiana");`, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant to make `CreateState` static? Why don't you make the constructor throw the error?

Comment: @TylerCrompton - yes, I had meant to make that `static` (edited). Personally, I'm not a fan of throwing an exception from a constructor when you pass in data that isn't obviously wrong. It's one thing if you pass in a `null`, or a negative value for an array index, etc. But if you ask for a string and I give you a string, I expect that to work. That being said, you certainly could just throw the exception from the constructor if you prefer.